# Create vue components with raw html

Tags: components, web-component, vue.js

I know how to create a vue component constructor with simple html:

```
var Foo = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>This is foo!</p>'
})
```

But how to create it with a piece of DOM like this:

```
<div id="phone-list">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Search: <input v-model="query">
                Sort by:
                <select v-model="orderProp">
                    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
                    <option value="age">Newest</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>There is {{p.length}} phones total.</p>
                <ul class="phones">
                    <li v-for="phone in p.data | filterBy query | orderBy orderProp " class="thumbnail">

                        <a :href="'#/phones/' + phone.id" class="thumb"><img :src="phone.imageUrl"></a>
                        <a :href="'#/phones/' + phone.id">{{phone.name}}</a>
                        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I supposed to mix DOM strings with JS code in a JS file? I feel sick to do that.

Also, I have done some search and one solution may look like this:

```
Vue.extend({
    template: require('./call.html'),
    props: {
        call: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    //...
```

However, this solution requires me to stick with some bundle tools like `webpack` or `browserify`.

Is there a way to create vue component **clean(DOM saved in a sepearate file)** and **simple(not using bundle tools)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it seems that I have no choice but to **stick with webpack**.

Here, follow this article and you will gain **basic knowledge about the webpack**, including definition and installation and configuration and usage.[Diving into Webpack](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/09/24/diving-webpack/)

After you installed the webpack, you may want to `webpack` your js files like this:

```
Vue.extend({
    template: require('./call.html'),
    props: {
        call: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    //...
```

However, you may end up with an error like following in your CLI:

```
<div class="main"> Unexpected Token
...
...
```

Don't worry, this is happening because the webpack requires **different loaders to handle with different type of files**, such as html, css, less.For more detail, check this: 
webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html#styling

So, install the [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader) to handle with html files.

And then change your js file into:

```
Vue.extend({
    template: require('html!./call.html'),
    props: {
        call: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    //...
```

and `webpack` it in your CLI, everything should work as expected now!

Answer (score 0):

To construct a template string, you could use the `grave accent` (also called a `back-tick`) (`) to enclose the string instead of single or double quotes.

```
var Foo = Vue.extend({
  template: `<div id="phone-list">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            Search: <input v-model="query">
            Sort by:
            <select v-model="orderProp">
              <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
              <option value="age">Newest</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>There is {{p.length}} phones total.</p>
            <ul class="phones">
              <li v-for="phone in p.data | filterBy query | orderBy orderProp " class="thumbnail">

                <a :href="'#/phones/' + phone.id" class="thumb"><img :src="phone.imageUrl"></a>
                <a :href="'#/phones/' + phone.id">{{phone.name}}</a>
                <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I notice that at the bottom of the page your url direct to, the Browser compatibility says this feature is not supported by Android?

Comment: This is a es6 feature